# Phonegap build google analytics plugin

Tags: cordova

Im testing the google analytics plugin with phonegap build.

I see that it register the index page on google analytics, but if I try to track a subpage(external page on my server) then that page is counted 5 times when I load it in the app?

I have the following code:

```
    var gaPlugin;

      function onBodyLoad()
            {     

             document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            function onDeviceReady()
            {
         document.addEventListener("resume",onResume,false);

        gaPlugin = window.plugins.gaPlugin;
        gaPlugin.init(successHandler, errorHandler, "UA-xxxxx-1", 10);

        gaPlugin.trackPage( successHandler, errorHandler, "index.html");

            }

        function onResume(){
            gaPlugin.trackPage( successHandler, errorHandler, "index.html");

          }
         function PageButtonClicked() {
    //gaPlugin.trackPage( successHandler, errorHandler, "http://www.mydomain.se/folder/news/news1.asp");
    gaPlugin.trackPage( nativePluginResultHandler, nativePluginErrorHandler, "http://www.mydomain.se/folder/news/news1.asp");
                }

        function successHandler (result) {
        alert('successHandler - '+result);

                }

        function errorHandler (error) {
        alert('errorHandler - '+error);

                }

        function goingAway() {
        gaPlugin.exit(successHandler, errorHandler);

                }

<body onLoad="onBodyLoad();" onunload="goingAway();">
```

1. In the PageButtonClicked function, witch should I use? Is nativePluginResultHandler calling some function in the phonegap.js file or? should I use the succesHandler?
2. Is the goingAway function really doing anything? Do I need it?
3. Maybe I should just count the index page?
4. Does it look like it should? Or where do I go wrong?

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to track here, looks like your calling trackPage on an external webpage? Are you navigating to this or what's actually going on?

Anyway: as far as I understand if you reference nativePluginResultHandler you also have to declare these as functions (not 100% sure), but using the success function should have the same result. What I do is basically:

```
gaTrackPageView: function(page) {
    // Call this function with the hash when the page changes
    var index = "index.html";
    var trackpage = index.concat(page);
    console.log('Tracking ' + trackpage);
    gaPlugin.trackPage(gaSuccess, gaFail, trackpage);
},

    gaSuccess: function() {
    // If the first connection is successful, track index page
    console.log('Successfully connected to Google Analytics');
},

gaFail: function() {
    // Generic failure function
    console.warn("Failed to connect to Google Analytics");
},
```

This is a Javascript SPA so I call the gaTrackPageView function with the hash.

I did just go through this myself, if you want you can check out my blog post about it at http://xc.ms , contains pretty much the full code for how I set it up - I'll be able to help out better if you share more of the code though because I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to track :)

//P